Bitbucket 7.21 Plugin - create custom rest endpoint
I need to create a custom rest endpoint in a Bitbucket Plugin (Bitbucket Server 7.21).
I didn't find any information, only Chatgpt sad, that I need to add "rest" and "rest-resource" to my atlassian-plugin.xml:


<rest key="rest-module" path="/rest" version="1.0">
        <description>Custom REST API</description>
    </rest>
    <rest-resource key="my-rest-resource"
                   class="com.avono.atlassian.plugins.bitbucket.mooglereview.api.MyRestResource"/>



But it also doesn't work. The url "http://:7990/rest/custom-api/1.0/example" gives me 404 back.
How to register the new api right? How the url would look like?
Thanks in advance.
